# Problem posting emails to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, smtp, sharepoint-discussion-board

We currently have a form for posting information with email to discussionboards in Sharepoint.
They have exaxtly the same settings for receiving emails. For some reason some of them gets the posted content and some don't. They seems to get to SMTP correctly and are shown in the Drop folder but then seems to dissapear without being added to the discussion boards.

The SMTP logs look a little strange as they contains addresses but no commands.

Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems only two out of 20 discussion boards was connected to their incoming email addresses even though they all hade proper settings.

Removed the email settings for the two that was working, renamed all existing discussion boards and created new ones with the same settings and now it works.